# Visual Basic Recording amount of seconds passed

Tags: vb.net, time

In my code I want to record the amount of seconds passed.  I was using `Second(Now)` to measure how much time has passed since a point and used the integer in comparisons but have realised that if the minute ends, it goes to zero.  This led me to add in `Minute(Now)` so that I could multiply this by 60 then add on `Second(Now)` but there is a similar problem of this number becoming zero once the hour passes.

What can I use instead of this to record the amount of seconds elapsed after a certain time.

Comment: This code is in C# but it shows how to obtain relative times using the .NET framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650674.aspx

Comment: Use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) or just use [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) to grab your start and end values and then use [`Datetime.Subtract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx) and convert from there using the `Datetime.TotalSeconds` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **TimeSpan** to register the difference between two **Now DateTime** by using the `DateTime.substract` method. here is an illustration. **Only after the operation do we convert the elapsed time into the unit we desire to use** (for example seconds in our case)

```
    Static start_time As DateTime
    Static stop_time As DateTime
    Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan

    start_time = Now

    ''' Processing here
    stop_time = Now

    elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
    Dim totalSecondsStr = elapsed_time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000000")
```